# TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable in scipy.optimize.minimize Library

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, optimization, scipy

Hi I am trying to implement an Optimization Paper "Optimal Kernel Selection in
Kernel Fisher Discriminant Analysis" and I have implemented the code for it. However, I get this error after trying different methods. I use scipy.optimize.minimize function from the scipy library https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#rdd2e1855725e-5

my code is as below:

```
def c_func(theta):

    data_pima = pd.read_csv('~/Documents/Uwaterloo_Study_Docs/ECE_602/Project_final/Dataset/PIMA/pima-indians-diabetes.csv')
    data_pima.rename(columns={'1':'Target', '6':'Pregnancies', '148':'Glucose', '72':'BloodPressure', '35':'SkinThickness', '0': 'Insulin',                                                    '33.6': 'BMI', '0.627':'DiabeticPedigreeFunction','50':'Age'},inplace=True)
    X = data_pima.loc[:,:'Age'].values
    y = data_pima['Target'].values
    data_pima_positive = data_pima.loc[(data_pima['Target'] > 0)]
    data_pima_negative = data_pima.loc[(data_pima['Target'] < 1)]


    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30,random_state=42)

    sq_dist = pdist(X, 'sqeuclidean')
    sigma = [10**(0.1), 10**(-0.7), 10**(-0.4), 10**(-0.1), 10**(0.2), 10**(0.5), 10**(0.8), 10**(1.1), 10**(1.4), 10**(1.7)]

    G = 0
    for value in range(10):
        gamma = 1/(sigma[value]**2)
        gamma = -gamma * theta[value] 
        mat_sqr_dist = squareform(sq_dist)
        g = np.exp(gamma * mat_sqr_dist)
        G = np.add(G, g)

    # number of positive sample from the dataset
    m_plus = len(data_pima_positive.index)
    data_pima_positive = data_pima_positive.values
    m_minus = len(data_pima_negative.index)
    one_plus = np.ones(m_plus)
    one_minus = np.ones(m_minus)
    I_plus = np.identity(m_plus)
    J_plus_1value = np.dot(one_plus, one_plus.T)
    J_plus = (1/np.sqrt(m_plus)) * (I_plus - (1/m_plus) * J_plus_1value)
    I_minus = np.identity(m_minus)
    J_minus_1value = np.dot(one_minus, one_minus.T)
    J_minus = (1/np.sqrt(m_minus)) * (I_minus - (1/m_minus) * J_minus_1value)

    J = linalg.block_diag(J_plus, J_minus)
    a_plus_1 = (1/m_plus)* one_plus
    a_minus_1  = (1/m_minus)* one_minus
    zeros_a_plus = np.zeros(len(a_minus_1))
    a_plus = np.block([a_plus_1, zeros_a_plus])
    zeros_a_minus = np.zeros(len(a_plus_1))
    a_minus = np.block([zeros_a_minus, a_minus_1])
    a = a_plus - a_minus
    lambda_val = 10**(-8)
    I = np.identity(len(J))
    J_G = np.matmul(J,G)
    lambda_I = lambda_val*I
    J_G_J = np.matmul(J_G, J)
    value_1 = (lambda_I + J_G_J)
    J_G_a = np.matmul(J_G,a)
    G_J = np.matmul(G,J)
    aT_G_J = np.matmul(a.T,G_J)
    G_a = np.matmul(G,a)
    aT_G_a = np.matmul(a.T, G_a)
    value_1Inv = linalg.inv(value_1)
    aT_G_J_value1Inv = np.matmul(aT_G_J, value_1Inv)
    aT_G_J_value1Inv_J_G_a = np.matmul(aT_G_J_value1Inv, J_G_a)
    func_val = (1/lambda_val)*(aT_G_J_value1Inv_J_G_a - aT_G_a)
    return func_val


if __name__ == "__main__":

    import numpy as np 
    import pandas as pd 
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform 
    from scipy import linalg
    from scipy.optimize import linprog
    from scipy import optimize as optimize

    theta_val = np.array([0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1])

    value = c_func(theta_val)
    result = optimize.minimize(value, theta_val, method='Newton-CG', jac=True, options={'disp':True})
    print(result)
```

Here is the detailed error that I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_project.py", line 76, in <module>
    result = optimize.minimize(value, theta_val, method='Newton-CG', jac=True, options={'disp':True})

  File "/home/somesh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py", line 607, in minimize
    **options)

  File "/home/somesh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 1588, in _minimize_newtoncg
    old_fval = f(x0)

  File "/home/somesh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 327, in function_wrapper
    return function(*(wrapper_args + args))

  File "/home/somesh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 65, in __call__

    fg = self.fun(x, *args)

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable
```

Can anyone help me in resolving this error?

log IndexError: (for context see comments discussion beneath)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_project.py", line 120, in <module>
    result = optimize.minimize(c_func, theta, method='Newton-CG', jac =True, options={'disp':True})

  File "/home/somesh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py", line 607, in minimize
    **options)

  File "/home/somesh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 1588, in _minimize_newtoncg
    old_fval = f(x0)

  File "/home/somesh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 327, in function_wrapper
    return function(*(wrapper_args + args))

  File "/home/somesh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 66, in __call__
    self.jac = fg[1]

IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

Answer (score 0):

So your issue here is that you've already evaluated `c_func`.

The `minimize` routine expects a ***callable*** and `c_func` itself is callable but when you call `c_func` on `theta_val` you get a float (or perhaps an array of floats. This/these are the ***return values*** of your `c_func`.

If you want to find the minimal value from the grid you can just evaluate the function and find the smallest value. What `minimize` does for you is accepts `c_func` and searches the argument space to find an optimal `theta_val`.

The second argument to `minimize` should be a starting value of `theta_val`. 
It may be helpful for you to read (if you haven't already) the tutorial for minimize:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#nelder-mead-simplex-algorithm-method-nelder-mead

to get an idea of how it works.

The call you probably want is not:

```
result = optimize.minimize(value, theta_val, method='Newton-CG', jac=True, options={'disp':True})
```

rather:

```
result = optimize.minimize(c_func, theta_val, method='Newton-CG', jac=True, options={'disp':True})
```

Which should work and return an `OptimizeResult` object.

Comment: When I try your approach I get this error: IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.  It doesn't optimize.

Comment: @SomeshGuptait looks like the only place you use `theta` is the line: ```  for value in range(10):
        gamma = 1/(sigma[value]**2)
        gamma = -gamma * theta[value] ``` is that correct? If so, can you redefine the function to calculate using a single `theta` and then can you see if that removes the error?

Comment: @LucasRobersI need to optimize this with theta as a vector rather than as a scalar in order to be consistent with the paper. However, when I try with your suggestion I get this error:  --> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: @SomeshGupta ok if you'd like help debugging the IndexError then you'll need to post the error you receive when placing the correct call against `scipy.minimize` I can't really help you debug an error with the type of exception alone. Please post the full stacktrace.

Comment: I have added it in the body as 'log IndexError' for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that in the minimize library optimizing with Conjugate gradient method requires the gradient function or an array that need to be passed to the minimize function. If we don't pass the gradient then it gives the error.

I passed the gradient and it worked.

The modified code is:

```
def c_func_opt(theta):

    data_pima = pd.read_csv('~/Documents/Uwaterloo_Study_Docs/ECE_602    Project_final/Dataset/PIMA/pima-indians-diabetes.csv')
    data_pima.rename(columns={'1':'Target', '6':'Pregnancies',  '148':'Glucose', '72':'BloodPressure', '35':'SkinThickness', '0': 'Insulin','33.6': 'BMI', '0.627':'DiabeticPedigreeFunction','50':'Age'},inplace=True)
    X = data_pima.loc[:,:'Age'].values
    y = data_pima['Target'].values
    data_pima_positive = data_pima.loc[(data_pima['Target'] > 0)]
    data_pima_negative = data_pima.loc[(data_pima['Target'] < 1)]


    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30,random_state=42)

    sq_dist = pdist(X, 'sqeuclidean')
    sigma = [10**(0.1), 10**(-0.7), 10**(-0.4), 10**(-0.1), 10**(0.2), 10**(0.5), 10**(0.8), 10**(1.1), 10**(1.4), 10**(1.7)]
    mat_sqr_dist = squareform(sq_dist)

    G = 0
    G_list = []
    eq9_value = 0

    for value in range(10):
        gamma = 1/(sigma[value]**2)
        gamma = -gamma 
        g = np.exp(gamma * mat_sqr_dist)
        G_g = theta[value] * g
        G_list.append(G_g)
        G = np.add(G, G_g)

    m_plus = len(data_pima_positive.index)
    data_pima_positive = data_pima_positive.values
    m_minus = len(data_pima_negative.index)
    one_plus = np.ones(m_plus)
    one_minus = np.ones(m_minus)
    I_plus = np.identity(m_plus)
    J_plus_1value = np.dot(one_plus, one_plus.T)
    J_plus = (1/np.sqrt(m_plus)) * (I_plus - (1/m_plus) * J_plus_1value)
    I_minus = np.identity(m_minus)
    J_minus_1value = np.dot(one_minus, one_minus.T)
    J_minus = (1/np.sqrt(m_minus)) * (I_minus - (1/m_minus) * J_minus_1value)

    J = linalg.block_diag(J_plus, J_minus)
    a_plus_1 = (1/m_plus)* one_plus
    a_minus_1  = (1/m_minus)* one_minus
    zeros_a_plus = np.zeros(len(a_minus_1))
    a_plus = np.block([a_plus_1, zeros_a_plus])
    zeros_a_minus = np.zeros(len(a_plus_1))
    a_minus = np.block([zeros_a_minus, a_minus_1])
    a = a_plus - a_minus
    lambda_val = 10**(-8)
    I = np.identity(len(J))
    J_G = np.matmul(J,G)
    lambda_I = lambda_val*I
    J_G_J = np.matmul(J_G, J)
    value_1 = (lambda_I + J_G_J)
    J_G_a = np.matmul(J_G,a)
    G_J = np.matmul(G,J)
    aT_G_J = np.matmul(a.T,G_J)
    G_a = np.matmul(G,a)
    aT_G_a = np.matmul(a.T, G_a)
    value_1Inv = linalg.inv(value_1)
    aT_G_J_value1Inv = np.matmul(aT_G_J, value_1Inv)
    aT_G_J_value1Inv_J_G_a = np.matmul(aT_G_J_value1Inv, J_G_a)
    func1_val = (1/lambda_val)*(aT_G_J_value1Inv_J_G_a - aT_G_a)

    eq9_value = 0
    for index_k in range(10):
        gamma = 1/(sigma[value]**2)
        gamma = -gamma 
        g = np.exp(gamma * mat_sqr_dist)
        theta_aT = theta[index_k] * a.T 
        theta_aT_g = np.matmul(theta_aT, g)
        theta_aT_g_a = np.matmul(theta_aT_g, a) 
        eq9_value += theta_aT_g_a

    func2_val = (1/lambda_val) * (aT_G_a - eq9_value)

    return func2_val


def c_func(theta):

    data_pima = pd.read_csv('~/Documents/Uwaterloo_Study_Docs/ECE_602/Project_final/Dataset/PIMA/pima-indians-diabetes.csv')
    data_pima.rename(columns={'1':'Target', '6':'Pregnancies', '148':'Glucose', '72':'BloodPressure', '35':'SkinThickness', '0': 'Insulin','33.6': 'BMI', '0.627':'DiabeticPedigreeFunction','50':'Age'},inplace=True)
    X = data_pima.loc[:,:'Age'].values
    y = data_pima['Target'].values
    data_pima_positive = data_pima.loc[(data_pima['Target'] > 0)]
    data_pima_negative = data_pima.loc[(data_pima['Target'] < 1)]

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30,random_state=42)

    sq_dist = pdist(X, 'sqeuclidean')
    sigma = [10**(0.1), 10**(-0.7), 10**(-0.4), 10**(-0.1), 10**(0.2), 10**(0.5), 10**(0.8), 10**(1.1), 10**(1.4), 10**(1.7)]
    mat_sqr_dist = squareform(sq_dist)

    G = 0 
    for value in range(10):
        gamma = 1/(sigma[value]**2)
        gamma = -gamma  
        g = np.exp(gamma * mat_sqr_dist)
        G_g = theta[value] * g 
        G = np.add(G, G_g)

    # number of positive sample from the dataset
    m_plus = len(data_pima_positive.index)
    data_pima_positive = data_pima_positive.values
    m_minus = len(data_pima_negative.index)
    one_plus = np.ones(m_plus)
    one_minus = np.ones(m_minus)
    I_plus = np.identity(m_plus)
    J_plus_1value = np.dot(one_plus, one_plus.T)
    J_plus = (1/np.sqrt(m_plus)) * (I_plus - (1/m_plus) * J_plus_1value)
    I_minus = np.identity(m_minus)
    J_minus_1value = np.dot(one_minus, one_minus.T)
    J_minus = (1/np.sqrt(m_minus)) * (I_minus - (1/m_minus) * J_minus_1value)
    J = linalg.block_diag(J_plus, J_minus)
    a_plus_1 = (1/m_plus)* one_plus
    a_minus_1  = (1/m_minus)* one_minus
    zeros_a_plus = np.zeros(len(a_minus_1))
    a_plus = np.block([a_plus_1, zeros_a_plus])
    zeros_a_minus = np.zeros(len(a_plus_1))
    a_minus = np.block([zeros_a_minus, a_minus_1])
    a = a_plus - a_minus
    lambda_val = 10**(-8)
    I = np.identity(len(J))
    J_G = np.matmul(J,G)
    lambda_I = lambda_val*I
    J_G_J = np.matmul(J_G, J)
    value_1 = (lambda_I + J_G_J)
    J_G_a = np.matmul(J_G,a)
    G_J = np.matmul(G,J)
    aT_G_J = np.matmul(a.T,G_J)
    G_a = np.matmul(G,a)
    aT_G_a = np.matmul(a.T, G_a)
    value_1Inv = linalg.inv(value_1)
    aT_G_J_value1Inv = np.matmul(aT_G_J, value_1Inv)
    aT_G_J_value1Inv_J_G_a = np.matmul(aT_G_J_value1Inv, J_G_a)
    func_val = (1/lambda_val)*(aT_G_J_value1Inv_J_G_a - aT_G_a)

    grad = []
    for value in range(10):
        gamma = 1/(sigma[value]**2)
        gamma = -gamma  
        g = np.exp(gamma * mat_sqr_dist)
        aT_g = np.matmul(a.T, g)
        aT_g_a = np.matmul(aT_g, a)
        grad.append(aT_g_a)
    return sq_dist, sigma, a, J, grad

def gradient_value(grad):
    lambda_va = 10**(-8)
    grad = (-1/lambda_va)*grad
    return grad


if __name__ == "__main__":

    import numpy as np 
    import pandas as pd 
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform 
    from scipy import linalg
    from scipy.optimize import LinearConstraint
    from scipy import optimize as optimize
    import cvxpy as cvx

    theta = np.array([0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1])
    sq_dist, sigma, a, J, grad = c_func(theta)
    grad = np.array(grad)
    grad_val = gradient_value(grad)
    one_vec = np.ones(len(theta))
    one_vec_t_theta = np.matmul(one_vec.T, theta)
    result = optimize.minimize(c_func_opt, theta, method='Newton-CG', jac =     gradient_value, options={'disp':True})   #constraints= cons,
    print(result)
```

Output:

```
Warning: Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.
         Current function value: -16171400.005492
         Iterations: 1
         Function evaluations: 33
         Gradient evaluations: 25
         Hessian evaluations: 0
     fun: -16171400.005492399
     jac: array([-1.025e+10, -1.025e+10, -1.025e+10, -1.025e+10, -1.025e+10,
       -1.025e+10, -1.025e+10, -1.025e+10, -1.025e+10, -1.025e+10])
 message: 'Warning: Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.'
    nfev: 33
    nhev: 0
     nit: 1
    njev: 25
  status: 2
 success: False
       x: array([102.5, 102.5, 102.5, 102.5, 102.5, 102.5, 102.5, 102.5, 102.5,
   102.5])
```